# how to display all snapshots in my aws account using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

the aim of this program is to delete snapshots that are older than 60 days. when run it displays the following error " a=snapshot[s].start_time
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'start_time' " This is my code

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
   import boto3
   import datetime
   client = boto3.client('ec2')
   snapshot= client.describe_snapshots()
   for s in snapshot:
     a=snapshot[s].start_time
     b=a.date()
     c=datetime.datetime.now().date()
     d=c-b
       if d.days>60 :
           snapshot[s].delete(dry_run=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the line `a=snapshot[s].start_time`, use `a=s.start_time`

Note I would change "snapshot" to "snapshots". then in your for loop:

```
for snapshot in snapshots:
```

This makes the code easier to read and clear on what your variables represent.

Another item is that `start_time` is a string. You will need to parse this to get a number. Here is an example to help you:

```
delete_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=days)
for snapshot in snapshots:
    start_time = datetime.strptime(
        snapshot.start_time,
        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'
    )

    if start_time < delete_time:
        ***delete your snapshot here***
```

Comment: is my for loop completely wrong (ignore the syntax) I'm asking concept wise.

Comment: Your for loop is OK. It is just that when you reference "s" again you are using it against "snashot" as in "snapshot[s]" which is not correct. Just reference "s" in your for loop. This is why I recommend renaming "snapshot" to "snapshots" and "s" to "snapshot". Clearer meanings.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it-

```
import boto3
import json
import sys
from pprint import pprint
region = 'us-east-1'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region)
resp = ec2.describe_instances()
resp_describe_snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['*******'])
snapshot =  resp_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']
snapshots = [''];
for snapshotIdList in resp_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']:
    snapshots.append(snapshotIdList.get('SnapshotId'))
for id in snapshots:
    print(id)
```